# How to send Access-Token in response from devise-auth-token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, devise-token-auth

I'm Using devise auth token for authentication  in my rails application and I want to return uid , client and access-token in the header of the response

```
def custom_registration_function
   new_user = User.new(....)
   if(new_user.save)

   // here i want to return the header to the response
   end
end
```